# How to compare variables in blade template

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

Hellow Guys,
Im trying to compare 2 variables in my blade template

My controller

```
$files = \File::files('images');

     foreach ($files as $file) {
          $info[] = pathinfo($file);
     }

$books = File::where('status', 1)->select('name')->get();

return view('cataloged.read', compact(['info','books']));
```

In my view
trying some like this

```
@foreach($info as $inf)
 @if(isset($books))
     @if($inf['basename'] == $books->name)
         Match
     @else
         No Match
     @endif
 @endif  
@endforeach
```

This work just for the last record - I have 2 records in my database - 
so its only working for the second record in this case...

What should I do?

Thanks for the help guys!

**EDIT**

```
 @foreach($books as $book)
           @foreach($info as $file)
              @if($book->name == $file['basename'])
                <p>Book</p>
              @else
                <p>No Book</p> 
              @endif
           @endforeach
  @endforeach
```

I only have 4 book in my database so this is working good

```
@if($book->name == $file['basename'])
       <p>Book</p>
@endif
```

Book 
Book
Book
Book

But when i use @else im gettin like this
Book No book 6 times
Book No book 6 times
Book No book 6 times
Book No book 6 times

Comment: Books is an array so you'll need to iterate over it as well

Comment: both files in the same directory?

Answer (score 0):

Since, `$books` is also array. You should probably do something like this:

```
@foreach($info as $inf)
    @if(isset($books))
        @foreach($books as $book)
            @if($inf['basename'] == $book->name)
                Match
            @else
                No Match
            @endif
        @endforeach
    @endif
@endforeach
```

**Edit**

```
<?php
    $i = 0;
    $count = count($books);
?>
    @foreach($info as $file)
        @if(($i<$count)?($books[$i]->name == $file['basename']):false)
            <p>Book</p>
        @else
            <p>No Book</p>
        @endif
        <?php $i++ ?>
    @endforeach
```

However, if the book is not supposed to be in an array then you should write `File::where('status', 1)->select('name')->first();` instead of `File::where('status', 1)->select('name')->get();`

Comment: I did but it doesnt working :( and i dont know why...really weird day

Comment: I have edited and provided a new edit. So, please check whether it works or not.

Comment: Not working man... Undefined offset: 4 and i tried with a @while($i<count($books)) but still not working this is really weird

Comment: That error is showing up because the number of book and the file are different. If they are different then there is no use in using that also. This code works only if the number of book record and number of file base name are same. So, I have again changed the edit code. Please try that.. it may work

Comment: Oh man, that was really close... gettin Bookx2 and No Boox x5